# Bootstrap Datetimepicker ignoring all options

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Hey I am trying to use the bootstrap datetimepicker, but it seems as if every option I set is ignored. The default datetimepicker is displayed but I can't modify it in any way with the options given [in the documentation](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#options). You can find the (not) working [fiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/bdv8nrhw/2/), where I am setting the sideByside attribute which obviously is not working.

This is my javascript

```
$(function () {
    $('#bootstrap-datetimepicker-wrapper').datetimepicker({
        defaultDate: "11/1/2013",
        disabledDates: [
            moment("10/02/2014"),
            new Date(2014, 10, 21),
            "10/05/2014 00:53"
        ],
        sideBySide: true,
    });
});
```

On the html site I pretty much use the minimum setup descripted [here](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#example5)

Comment: What exactly isn't working for you? Seems to be working just fine in Chrome.

Comment: @FilipB.Vondrášek the default datetimepicker is displayed for me to, just setting the options doesn't work. I edited the question to make this more clear. You can try playing around with the options (described here: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#options ) if you want to. for me in chrome and firefox it doesn't work (e.g. in the fiddle you see that obviously it isn't displayed sideByside but I set that option)

Comment: Are you sure you are including the correct JS files? The files in your fiddle are pointing to this repo: https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker - if you look at their website (http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/demo.php) and look at the examples they seem quite different from your code - none of your properties are supported, hence ignored

Comment: @BirgitMartinelle thanks a lot! But it seems as if the problem isn't solved. I updated the fiddle and now include the same files they do here: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#options (that is official documentation/demo), and it looks quite different. but somehow the options still are ignored (which seems a bit to much of a coincidence to myself)... But thanks a lot for that tip, I got confused because there are two different datetimepickers which have nearly the same markup and functionality and user numbers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you check the JS libraries you're including match the examples/documentation you use to implement. Your original fiddle pulled in sources from here: http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ but you followed instructions for this plugin: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Ok - check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bdv8nrhw/3/

Your second attempt was very close - you still used

```
`<input value="" class="form-control" id="id_starting_time" name="starting_time" title="" type="text" data-date-pickDate="false" />`
```

data-date-pickDate="false" was preventing your date-picker to work.
You also don't have to initialize with

```
pickDate: true,
pickTime: true
```

those are defaults anyways - they won't hurt but are not necessary - Enjoy ;)

Comment: thanks, I think would be nice if you implemented noted in the answer that I first used the wrong library maybe, because they actually are very similiar and easy to confuse, maybe it will help someone